# golang : network response from ioutil.ReadAll() is empty, connection reset by peer

Tags: networking, tcp, go, modbus

I'm trying to test out performing a simple TCP MODBUS read of a single register from a device emulator.  When running the code it is showing a response of 0 bytes and I get the message "connection reset by peer".  Any ideas as to why it's not working?

UPDATE, my request was incorrect, the correct working MODBUS TCP poll code is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

// TCP MODBUS client
func main() {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "192.168.98.114:502")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    numRegs := 1
    # make a MODBUS TCP request (be careful, the format is different to MODBUS serial)
    request := []byte{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01}
    n, err := conn.Write(request)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    expectedResponseLen := 5 + 2 * numRegs
    response := make([]byte, expectedResponseLen)
    n, err = conn.Read(response)
    conn.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%02x ", response[i])
    }
    fmt.Println("\n")
}
```

Comment: This does seem to be a network related problem and not a problem with your code. `connection reset by peer` might be the result of nobody listening on that port or the service not answering your call for some reason. Did you check for that?

Comment: `connection reset by peer` normally means that the client accepted the connection but hung up after it received your request. Maybe the request is faulty? (additionally, I think you meant to use `fmt.Fprint`)

Comment: Thanks Tom, my request was malformed, the correct code is now above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally I thought that `fmt.Fprintf` may be changing the request data on the way out, but [this  example](http://play.golang.org/p/rM65Ihgwk7) seems to work OK.

However, I would still recommend using the lower-level `Write/Read` instead of `fmt.Fprintf/ioutil.ReadAll`:

```
req := []byte { 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0xd5, 0xca }

n, err := conn.Write(req)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("write error:", err)
    return
}

fmt.Printf("wrote %d bytes for request: %#v", n, req)

rsp := make([]byte, 64)

n, err = conn.Read(rsp)

fmt.Printf("received %d bytes in response: %#v", n, rsp[:n])

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("read error:", err)
}
```

Comment: I reworked the code to use con.Write.  The main problem I had was that my request packet was malformed.  I've updated the code in my post with a working version.